# How can I call .map() on ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional?

Tags: swift

`Optional<T>` has `map` method.

```
/// If `self == nil`, returns `nil`.  Otherwise, returns `f(self!)`.
func map<U>(f: (T) -> U) -> U?
```

When we want to convert `Int?` to `UInt64?`, we can:

```
let iVal:Int? = 42
let i64Val = iVal.map { UInt64($0) }
```

Instead of:

```
var i64Val:UInt64?
if let iVal = iVal {
    i64Val = UInt64(iVal)
}
```

Here, `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<T>` has same method:

```
/// If `self == nil`, returns `nil`.  Otherwise, returns `f(self!)`.
func map<U>(f: (T) -> U) -> U!
```

So I tried... and failed :(

```
let iVal:Int! = 42
let i64Val = iVal.map { UInt64($0) } 
//           ^    ~~~  [!] error: 'Int' does not have a member named 'map'
```

Here is the question: **How can I call this method?**

Comment: I think having `map` function on `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<T>` is pointless. Compiler already converts it to the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let i64Val = (iVal  as ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional).map {UInt64($0)}
```

Comment: Thanks! but... I think, I will not use this :/

Answer (score 2):

```
let iVal:Int! = 42
let i64Val = (iVal as Int?).map { UInt64($0) }
```

Comment: Not bad :) But, this actually calls `Optional<Int>.map`, not the `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` one. Although, I think, your answer  is the most useful in **practical use cases**.

Comment: true, but given implicitly unwrapped optionals are landmines, going out of your way to preserve them seems questionable :-)

Comment: `let i64Val = map(iVal) { UInt64($0) }`
also gets you the explicit optional version and is probably a little more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message clears it up: `error: 'Int' does not have a member named 'map'`. It says `Int` not `Int!` so the value is already unwrapped when trying to call a method.

So just use:

```
let iVal:Int! = 42
let i64Val = UInt64(iVal)
```